# Large app size in itunes store

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework, app-store-connect

I have uploaded an ionic app to the itunes store. The archive size that uploaded is only 24.6 MB. But after uploading it shows 57.5 MB. When i checked in itunes connect the estimated appstore file sizes shows more than 55 Mb for all devices where as the compressed file size there shows 24.6 Mb. How did the size increased after uploading to store? How can i reduce the estimated app size?[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The smaller size is the compressed size and the larger one is the install size. Apps are uncompressed as part of being installed.

You also asked about reducing the size of your app. Apple have a paper about this at https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1795/_index.html

Comment: Will it compress to half the size?

Comment: That's not uncommon for compression but it depends on the nature of what is in the app. An app that had a lot of text resource would compress more and one that had a lot of video would compress less (as the video is already compressed).